# error: ... was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm working on a queue in c++ and I'm having some issues with a weird compilation error:

> Queue.h:37:49: error: expected "," or "..." before "<" token
>   Queue.h: In copy constructor "Queue::Queue(Queue&)":
>   Queue.h:39:11: error: "other" was not declared in this scope
>   Queue.h: At global scope:
>   Queue.h:42:72: error: expected "," or "..." before "<" token
>   Queue.h: In member function "Queue& Queue::operator=(const Queue&)":
>   Queue.h:44:11: error: "other" was not declared in this scope

Can anyone help?

```
#if !defined QUEUE_SIZE
#define QUEUE_SIZE 30
#endif

template <class TYPE> class Queue
{
 private:
  TYPE *array;
 public:
  Queue(Queue& other);
  Queue();
  ~Queue();
  Queue& operator=(const Queue& other);
  TYPE pushAndPop(TYPE x);
};

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::Queue()
{
  array=new TYPE[QUEUE_SIZE];
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::~Queue()
{
  delete [] array;
}

template <class TYPE> TYPE Queue<TYPE>::pushAndPop(TYPE other)
{
  TYPE item = array[0];
  for(int x = 0; x<QUEUE_SIZE-1; x++){
    array[x]= array[x+1];
  }
  array[QUEUE_SIZE-1] = other;
  return item;
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>:: Queue(Queue&<TYPE> other)
{
  array = other.array;
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>& Queue<TYPE>:: operator=(const Queue&<TYPE> other)
{
  array = other->array;
}
```

Comment: `Queue&<TYPE>` -> `Queue<TYPE>&` or just leave out the `<TYPE>`. You should take by `const&` in a copy-ctor unless you have to use non-const `&`. Also there's a problem with you memory allocation when using a copy ctor (the same `array` will be deleted several times).

Answer (score 2):

You put **&** at wrong place:

update

```
template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>:: Queue(Queue&<TYPE> other)
                                               ^^
{
  array = other.array;
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>& Queue<TYPE>:: operator=(const Queue&<TYPE> other)
                                                                      ^^^
{
  array = other->array;    // other is a reference, not pointer
               ^^^
}
```

to

```
template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>:: Queue(Queue<TYPE>& other)
{
  //array = other.array;
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>& Queue<TYPE>:: operator=(const Queue<TYPE>& other)
{
  // check that it's not self-assign
  // make sure you release current memory
  // allocate new memory
  // copy over content of array
  // array = other.array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for the comments to see the changes. Also as pointed out by others change `Queue&<TYPE>` to `Queue<TYPE>&`.

```
template <class TYPE> class Queue
{
 private:
  TYPE *array;
 public:
  Queue(const Queue& other); // Take a const reference instead
  Queue();
  ~Queue();
  Queue& operator=(const Queue& other);
  TYPE pushAndPop(TYPE x);
};

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::Queue()
{
  array=new TYPE[QUEUE_SIZE];
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::~Queue()
{
  delete [] array;
  array = NULL; // Be safe
}

template <class TYPE> TYPE Queue<TYPE>::pushAndPop(TYPE other)
{
  TYPE item = array[0];
  for(int x = 0; x<QUEUE_SIZE-1; x++){
    array[x]= array[x+1];
  }
  array[QUEUE_SIZE-1] = other;
  return item;
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::Queue(const Queue<TYPE>& other)
{
  array=new TYPE[QUEUE_SIZE];

  for(int x = 0; x<QUEUE_SIZE; x++){
    array[x]= other.array[x]; // Deep copy of array is required
  }
}

template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>& Queue<TYPE>:: operator=(const Queue<TYPE>& other)
{
   // this piece of code is repeated in copy-ctor, good candidate to extract as a method  
   for(int x = 0; x<QUEUE_SIZE; x++){
    array[x]= other.array[x]; // Deep copy of array is required, 
  }

  return *this;
}
```

Comment: When the assignment operator is called, storage has already been allocated in one of the ctors and `array` points to valid memory. Either `delete` it before assigning a new pointer to `array` or re-use the memory. (btw this is why one should use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` ;) As billz pointed out, check for self-assignment.

Comment: No problem. Should not have posted those remarks one by one... (but didn't saw all of the issues immediately). Maybe you could clean up the comments?